# get on ListNavigation click in the action bar

Tags: android, list, actionbarsherlock

I have a list in my action bar sherlock. I want to get when user click on that list.
I don't want to know when user click on an item, i already know that (onNavigationItemSelected).

in my onCreate():

```
// Set action bar
final ActionBar actionBar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar.getNavigationMode() != ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST) {
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
}
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mSelectionAdapter = new SelectionAdapter(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item, kinds);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSelectionAdapter, this);
```

I want to detect programatically when user click on the list navigation in my action bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be be notified when an actionbar item such as a list menu is clicked, then you must override `onMenuItemSelected` as follows:

```
    @Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
int itemId = item.getItemId();
//using logcat you may see what the list item id is?
 Log.i(TAG, "clicked actionbar itemid is: " + itemId );

//here you can setup a listener for every actionbar item selected
    switch (itemId) {
//android.R.id.list might not be the one you are searching pls check it out and compare it to logcat and put the appropriate itemId here
    case android.R.id.list:
//do whatever you want to do when list item is clicked
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```